# Update table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

A MySQL database table has 2 primary keys. I am using a third party library for jQuery that has a DataGrid option. So far, I have tried using the datagrid view but it is assigning a serial number as the primary key, which is not what I want. How do I update the table from the datagrid view by using one of the primary keys that I have provided?

*Edit:
Code to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`ProductBrand` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`productcategory` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`productCode` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`productSerial` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`productName` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
`productDescription` TEXT NOT NULL,
`productInstock` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
`productOrder` SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL,
`productTransit` SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL,
`productDispute` SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL,
`productText` VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
`productHtml` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
`productImage` BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
`productstatus` VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`productbrand`,`productCode`,`productSerial`),
INDEX (`productName`),
INDEX (`productbrand`),
INDEX (`productcode`),
INDEX (`productserial`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Single table can't have two primary key.
I think you have combined two columns and made primary key.
please provide database table.

Comment: Added database table to post

Comment: Just curious, and I am not judging you, why do you have 12 primary keys?